# How to retrieve HTTP request header using CGI with BASH

Tags: bash, server, cgi, backend

I use a CGI script that calls a Java program using Apache 2.4.41.
The script is the following:

```
#!usr/bin/bash
java \
 -Dcgi.content_type=$CONTENT_TYPE \
 -Dcgi.content_length=$CONTENT_LENGTH \
 -Dcgi.request_method=$REQUEST_METHOD \
 -Dcgi.query_string=$QUERY_STRING \
 -Dcgi.server_name=$SERVER_NAME \
 -Dcgi.server_port=$SERVER_PORT \
 -Dcgi.script_name=$SCRIPT_NAME \
 -Dcgi.path_info=$PATH_INFO \
 -Dcgi.http_cookie=$HTTP_COOKIE \
 -classpath /home/be \
 cgi.UserEndpointCGI
```

The client sends to the endpoint a custom header to tell the server which function is request. The header contains the key-value:

```
Y-Request: function_name
```

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve `Y-Request: function_name` header field and i couldn't find an answer on the net.

Answer (score 0):

From your example , this how you use a arbitrary header

```
 -Dcgi.http_cookie=$HTTP_COOKIE \
```

The header `Y-Request`  must be available in the variable `HTTP_Y_REQUEST` .

You CGI script has a big security, someone can inject arbritrary shell command  , you must quote the usage of all variables .

```
-Dcgi.http_cookie="$HTTP_COOKIE" \
```